# D3 taking an index string and classifying a circle as hidden or not

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I currently have a Javascript function that takes in a string of form "01001", for example, which means that the second and fifth data rows/elements are "marked/selected" in a data table.

I would like to look at this string, and in D3, mark all the circles corresponding to the data elements that are represented by 1's in the string (ie. their .classed is not "hidden").

How exactly would I do this? Here is my current implementation, but I'm pretty sure it's not highlighting the right circles on my graph.

```
      function brushupdate(index) {
      var e = brush.extent();

        svg.selectAll("circle").classed("hidden", function (d, i) {
            if (index[i] == 0) {
                return true;
            }
            else {
                return false;
            }
        });

        if (index.search('1') == -1) {
            svg.selectAll(".hidden").classed("hidden", false);
        }
    }
```

I'm not sure how iterating thruogh the string would work in D3.

Answer (score 1):

I would `split()` your string, then reading it as array you have your first element to look at the same index value in your array, so then easily in you create a `function(d, i) {}` and you take a look at the index of the element should be the same than the index of your binary array, so then you could react accordingly.

Answer (score 1):

As @Santiago suggested, you can use the `split` method to transform your string to a data array, and bind that array to your selection. **EDIT**: Changed the example to use circles instead of list elements.

```
// Split the string in individual characters
var dataString = "010011",
    dataArray  = dataString.split(''); // ['0', '1', '0', '0', '1', '1']

// Create a selection for the circles and bind it
// to the data array
var svg = d3.select('svg'),
    circles = svg.selectAll('circle').data(dataArray);

// Assign the classes 'zero' and 'one' using the data bound to each circle.
circles.enter().append('circle')
  .classed('zero', function(d) { return d === '0'; })
  .classed('one',  function(d) { return d === '1'; })
  .attr('cx', function(d, i) { return 50 + i * 50; })
  .attr('cy', 100)
  .attr('r', 20);

circles.exit().remove();
```

A working [jsBin](http://jsbin.com/jejale/2/) is available. The result should look like this:

[image: Classed circles]

Regards,

Comment: Could you explain the purpose behind each of the steps? I'm not exactly sure if I'm following. However, if I'm understanding this correctly, I could get the selection of all the circles with an unordered list appended using var ul = d3.selectAll("circle").append("ul");, then bind the string array onto it using var li = ul.selectAll("li").data(splitindex);, and then finally finalize the string array bind using li.enter().append("li");? How exactly does the d in  li.classed("hidden", function (d) { return +d === 0; }) know to look at the string array?

Comment: You can't use `ul` to append circles, it was just an example of how to split the data and use the `classed` method, sorry for the confusion. I updated the answer to include an example with circles.